# Evaluating the function 'System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.Listeners.get' timed out and needed to be aborted in unsafe way

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was doing .NET 4.8 upgrade on my company's Application as required because the Server's environment won't be supporting the old codes.

I upgraded the outdated packages including the System.Diagnostic.DiagnosticSource packages but some problem occurred when I run the solution in Visual Studio 2019, I get this pop up error:

[image]

I tried to find a solution for this and this link is the only thing I got for this solution

https://ask.csdn.net/questions/7146065

in this link, It says that I have to remove the App Insights from the web.config as "fixed" for my problem

but I don't really get why they suggest App Insights to be removed from web.config while knowing that this is very important for this application.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have one of the latest versions of Application Insights running as I do. There is a bug of some sort you can read about here https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2161.

I disabled IntelliTrace and the debugger stopped failing.
Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace

I hope that helps. I know it's not a true fix but please accept this as an answer. :-)